# form.validateFields() fails inside onValuesChange in ant design forms

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to programmatically submit and ant design (v4.3.4) form with validation but `form.validateFields()` always fails with `outOfDate: true` if it is inside `onValuesChange()`. (This form is a part of a larger form factory so I will eventually have to pass the form component to a props function which will then call submit.

```
const FormA = (props: StepProps) => {
  const [form] = useForm();

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      name="form-a"
      onValuesChange={async (changedValues, allValues) => {
        form.validateFields().
         then(values => console.log("PASSED").
         catch(errorInfo => console.log("FAILED", errorInfo));
      }}
    >
      <Form.Item 
      rules={[{ required: true }]} 
      name="item-a">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        rules={[{ required: true }]}
        name="item-b"
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        rules={[{ required: true }]}
        name="item-c"
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default FormA;
```

I have called the `form.validatedField()` function onValuesChange. I never get "PASSED" in the console, even when all inputs have values I always get 'FAILED' with the following errorInfo:

```
{
  errorFields: []
  outOfDate: true
  values: { ..}
}
```

If I remove the form.validateFields() from `onValuesChange` then it works fine.

I can't seem to figure out what is `outOfDate` and why does validation always fail in onValuesChange function.

Comment: I had pretty much the same issue and maybe my issue on `antd`'s GitHub will help you a bit in understanding the problem https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/26747

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to programmatically submit a form is by using `form.submit()` that's part of the [form instance](https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance). This function will submit and validate your form. Based on the validation result, `onFinish` or `onFinishFailed` will be called (see [Form API](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form)).

```
const FormA = (props: StepProps) => {
  const [form] = useForm();

  const handleOnFinish = (values) => {
    // handle valid form submission
  }

  const handleOnFinishFailed = ({ values, errorFields, outOfDate }) => {
    // handle invalid form submission
  }

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      name="form-a"
      onFinish={handleOnFinish]
      onFinishFailed={handleOnFinishFailed}
    >
      ...
    </Form>
  );
};

export default FormA;
```

The `outOfDate` issue is resolved when using this method. If you need additional validation handling for a form item, you can use `onChange` and `form.validateFields()` in the  components (see [issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/26747#issuecomment-693165910)).